# Не уменьшается количество денег Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно, чтоб при покупке предмета от общих денег отнималась только цена товара, но скрипт не уменьшает значение.

```
private bool isOpened = false;
public Text moneyText;
public Text lvl;
public int lvlCost = 5;

public void BuyNewLVL()
    {
        int moneyTextInt = int.Parse(moneyText.text);
        if(moneyTextInt >= lvlCost)
        {
            moneyTextInt-=lvlCost;
            moneyText.text = moneyTextInt.ToString();
            int lvlint = int.Parse(lvl.text);
            lvlint++;
            lvl.text = lvlint.ToString(); 
            

        }
        else if(moneyTextInt < lvlCost)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не совсем корректно обновляете moneyText.text.Сначала вы разбираете текст на int, а затем вычитаете из него lvlCost. Разумеется, это не будет обновлять moneyText.text.
Проще всего обновить moneyText.text после вычитания:

```
moneyText.text = (moneyTextInt - lvlCost).ToString();
```

Дополнительно укажите в `else if`, что вы хотите сделать, если у игрока мало денег.

```
else if(moneyTextInt < lvlCost)
{
    //Не хватает денег
}
```

Можно ещё проверить, больше ли значение moneyTextInt или равно lvlCost, прежде чем вычитать lvlCost из moneyTextInt.

```
int moneyTextInt = int.Parse(moneyText.text);
if (moneyTextInt >= lvlCost)
{
   moneyText.text = (moneyTextInt - lvlCost).ToString();
   int lvlint = int.Parse(lvl.text);
   lvlint++;
   lvl.text = lvlint.ToString(); 
}
else
{
    //Не хватает денег
}
```

Ещё можно попробовать `int.TryParse()` вместо `int.Parse()`, т.к. `int.Parse()` выдает исключение, когда входные данные не могут быть проанализированы, в то время как `TryParse` возвращает `false`

```
int moneyTextInt;
if (int.TryParse(moneyText.text, out moneyTextInt))
{
   if (moneyTextInt >= lvlCost)
   {
       moneyText.text = (moneyTextInt - lvlCost).ToString();
       int lvlint;
       if(int.TryParse(lvl.text, out lvlint))
       {
           lvlint++;
           lvl.text = lvlint.ToString(); 
       }
   }
   else
   {
       //Не хватает денег
   }
}
```

Может мой ответ вам поможет.

Comment: Нет, количество денег остается на месте.